# MySQL using outer query value as comma separated list in subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a simple subquery in MySQL that refers to a value in the outer query:

**a.foo** is a comma separated list: ABC,EFG,HIJ

**b.bar** is some associated data: 123,456,789

```
SELECT a.foo,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(b.bar) FROM table b WHERE b.foo IN(a.foo)) bar FROM table a;
```

This works fine if I run the subquery by itself, returning the associated data in a comma separated list, perfect!

However, as a subquery, I get just the first result.

What I *think* is happening is when referring to **a.foo** it's quoting the comma separated list as a string, because if I manually put in the values it works as expected.

Is there a way to reference an outer column value and unquote it in a subquery like this?

Comment: `.. WHERE LOCATE(b.foo, a.foo) ..`

Comment: This does work (thank you) but it scans every row for b.foo ... there are about 3 million rows :( I need it to use the index.

Comment: Trying to avoid a separate query ... which is plan b ...

Comment: *but it scans every row for b.foo* This is an effect of denormalized structure. Either normalize it (one value per row, not CSV, maybe in separate table) or convert to JSON array and create multivalued index.

Comment: Thanks again, unfortunately, I have no control over the schema ... plan b it is!